# NULL values in QGIS attribute tables not appearing

Tags: qgis, null

'NULL' is not appearing in my QGIS attribute tables. Columns that used to have 'NULL' in them are now just empty.

What could be the problem?

Comment: When you say used to have NULL in them what do you mean? Did you change anything? My first thought is that they've  been replaced with string that's just empty.

Comment: Thanks,
I mean, the empty spaces used to be "null', now they are just empty. I am new to qgis and having those null values was useful when writing command queries. But with empty spaces now, I can't figure how to write these commands anymore.

Comment: Just to check your settings... Can you open `Settings | Options | Data Sources (tab)` and see `Representation for NULL values` (in Feature attributes and table)`? In my case it is **NULL**.

Comment: I confirmed this strange behavior with QGIS 2.18.12. Then testing in reverse order: 2.18.11 to 2.18.7, the same. Looks like this is persistent. Removing .qgis2 folder has not work out so far. (I usually use QGIS 2.14 and have never seen this...)